# How to create X elements of a predefined type xamafin forms UI

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to create elements on the Xamarin forms UI based on user input but I do not know how to go about it. In the screenshot attached, I want to capture details pertaining to a user's family. Each member has a name, date of birth, phone number, and email address.

The user specifies the number of family members in the "Number of family members" field and clicks "Add", which creates the specified number of instances of the name, date of birth, phone number, and email address.

[image: Screenshot of sample UI].

How can I go about this?

Comment: use a CollectionView.  Create a template for your data entry, and then every time a new person is added, just add a new Person model to the ItemsSource.  Take some time to read the CollectionView docs and look at the samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrote a demo and achieve what jason said in the comment. Use a [collectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) and update `itemSource` with the family member user input in the entry:

In xaml:

```
<StackLayout Margin="20">

    <Label Text="number of familay numbers"/>
    <Entry x:Name="numberEntry" Placeholder="enter the number"/>

    <Button Text="add" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

    <CollectionView x:Name="testCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding familyMember}">

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                       ItemSpacing="20" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>

                    <Label Text= "name"/>
                    <Entry Placeholder="enter the number"/>

                    <Label Text= "phone"/>
                    <Entry Placeholder="enter the phone"/>

                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    </CollectionView>

</StackLayout>
```

In code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    viewModel vm;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new viewModel();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var text = numberEntry.Text;
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(text);

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            PersonalInfo memberOne = new PersonalInfo() { name = "", phone = "" };
            vm.familyMember.Add(memberOne);
        }

    }
}

public class viewModel {

    public ObservableCollection<PersonalInfo> familyMember { get; set; }

    public viewModel()
    {
        familyMember = new ObservableCollection<PersonalInfo>();

        //PersonalInfo memberOne = new PersonalInfo() {name = "jack", phone="516" };

        //familyMember.Add(memberOne);
    }
}

public class PersonalInfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

I uploaded a [sample project](https://github.com/XfHua/collectionView-Binding) here and feel free to ask me any question.

[image]